# Install e(fx)eclipse in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I tried to install e(fx)eclipse tools in Eclipse Mars but it not successful and show that message when I start Eclipse:

> You are not running your eclipse instance with Java8. The JavaFX tooling is disabled because of this.Make Java8 the default system java or adjust your eclipse.ini to pass -vm pointing to your Java8 install.

In case you want to turn off this check open your preferences and go to General > Startup and Shutdown and uncheck 'JavaFX Tooling Java Check"

[image]

Could anyone help me about this?

Comment: pretty obvious, isn't it? You're jre is a lower version than 8. Update to Java 8 and everything should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, maybe this is a reason. Do you know other tools or plugin for JavaFx in Eclipse? :)

Comment: Nope, sry. I'm not using JavaFX. But e(fx)eclipse is Java8-only according to the docs, so why not simply update to java8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated an update might be everything you need. I had a similar issue under Linux once, where there were two JVMs installed and the older one was in the projects build path.
You can check under the projects properties -> java build path if Java 1.8 is shown there.

Regarding tools: I don't think you'll need any. Try and get familiar with the JavaFX Scene Builder. It makes building a simple GUI super easy.

Comment: So we have to update our Java to version 8? Do we have any solution for java 7?

Comment: JavaFx should work with Java 7 as well. Try and add "jfxrt.jar" to the classpath:
Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs from... -> "jfxrt.jar".
If you're using Windows it should be located somewhere under "X:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.X_XX/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar"
Don't forget to actually pack the jar somewhere inside your program folder and use relative paths if you want to distribute the program.